# Why am I being prompted with an error message stating that Y may be used uninitialized when I initialized it?

Tags: c++

I just started writing C++ not too long ago. For my class, we were asked to write a program that allows the user to input data and then print out the data respectively. I wanted to verify that the user inputted their data incorrectly so I added an if-else statement. However, when I run the program it says warning: 'Y' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
          if (V == Y || V == y) {

It says this for Y, y, N, and n. What am I doing wrong? I thought I initialized these variables in the char assignment statement... Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int  principle;
double rate, time, interest, initInvest, total;
char V, Y, y, N, n;


cout << "Enter the initial amount of your investment: ";
cin >> initInvest;
cout << "The amount of your initial investment has been set to " << initInvest << "."
     << "\n\nEnter the investment principle as a real number: ";
cin >> principle;
cout << "The investment principle has been set to " << principle << "."
     << "\n\nEnter the amount of time that has passed since the initial deposit: ";
cin >> time;
cout << "The amount of time passed since the initial deposit has been set to " << time << "."
     << "\n\nEnter the investment rate as a decimal number: ";
cin >> rate;
cout << "The investment rate has been set to " << rate << ".\n\n"
     << "Please verify that the above values are correct Y/N: "; //verifies data in case user inputed values incorrectly
cin >> V; //verification value

     if (V == Y || V == y) {
        interest = principle*rate*time; //calculates interest earned
        total = initInvest+interest; //calculates total amount earned

        cout << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) << fixed << setprecision(3); //sets output for all floating-point values
        cout << "INITIAL INVESTMENT     INTEREST EARNED     TOTAL AMOUNT EARNED\n" //creates a neat table to
             << "------------------ --- --------------- --- -------------------\n" //display the gathered data
             << setw(18) << initInvest << setw(20) << interest << setw(24) << total << endl;
     }
     else if (V == N || V == n) { //re-initiates all before stated data
        cout << "\nPlease re-enter the data and try again.\n"
             << "Enter the initial amount of your investment: ";
        cin >> initInvest;
        cout << "The amount of your initial investment has been set to " << initInvest << "."
             << "\n\nEnter the investment principle as a real number: ";
        cin >> principle;
        cout << "The investment principle has been set to " << principle << "."
             << "\n\nEnter the amount of time that has passed since the initial deposit: ";
        cin >> time;
        cout << "The amount of time passed since the initial deposit has been set to " << time << "."
             << "\n\nEnter the investment rate as a decimal number: ";
        cin >> rate;
        cout << "The investment rate has been set to " << rate << ".\n\n"
             << "Please review the output values.\n"
             << "If they are still not correct, restart the program."; //gave the user a second chance to get it right
     }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you initialise it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare `V` with the character `y`, you should write `V == 'y'` (a character literal is written between single quotes).

The declaration `char y;` creates a variable named `y` that can store any character.

Comment: Suggestion: it’s a really common bug to write `v = 'y'` by mistake when you mean `v == 'y'`. It’s valid C or C++, but has a nasty side-effect. But, if you get in the habit of always writing the constant on the *left* of `==`, `'y' = v` will always fail to compile. This will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Lorehead It's valid C/C++, but any sane compiler will warn you about it. And since serious programming should use "treat warnings as errors," you should never have a real need for "Yoda conditionals."

Comment: Agree in the general case, but every now and then you wind up having to maintain a legacy system with an antique compiler that is nowhere near as bright. Also worked a few jobs where the code emitted megasmurftonnes of warnings that I was not allowed to fix because the code "worked". Recommendation: If you find yourself in one of these places don't stay there long. And charge extra.

Comment: @Angew Since compilers generally assume `((v = 'y'))` is intentional, I wouldn't say *never*.  But I admit the examples I can come up with are pretty contrived.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Thats Wrong Way Of Testing The Condition.

```
 if (V == Y || V == y) { //Wrong Way
```

It Should Be

```
 if (V == 'Y' || V == 'y') {
```

Comment: Why Do You Keep Writing Like This?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Capitalism, probably.